# Программа вместо числа присваивает переменной значение nan

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

Здраствуйте, на своем сайте я создаю формы для заполнения, которые затем идут на сервер, поэтому необходимо динамически создавать аттрибуты name, в массиве length хранится информация о количестве элементов в div .task. Необходимо при нажатии на большую кнопку с плюсом, чтобы для клонированных элементов изменялся name. div, который клонируется имеют класс icontest. Внутри эти элементы должны иметь name вида taskN[icontestN][некоторый параметр, на который не стоит обращать внимание]:
N - количество div класса task или класса icontest. При создание div .class появляется большая кнопка с плюсом, которая клонируя внутренний div должна увеличивать N в аттрибуте name. Вместо этого получается аттрибут типа task1[icontestNan][некоторый параметр], то есть N получается равно Nan. Почему Nan?

```css
* {
vertical-align: baseline;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}/*Отмена стилей браузера*/
body{
 height: 10000px;
}/*длина сайта(страницы)*/
textarea{
 color:black;
 border:1px solid red;
}/*настройка всех текстовых полей*/
.main_text{
 margin-top: 20px; 
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.task{
 display:none;
 top: 5px;
 position: relative;
 border:1px solid orange;
 width: 95%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*Настройка поля с Основным заданием*/
 .testtext1{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;

 
 
}/* поле С Заданием 1*/

.first{
 margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.icontest{
 float: left;
 width: 240px;
 height:auto;
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;

 
}/*Поле для всавляемого изображения*/
 #inputfile{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
}/* Кнопка для добавления файлов*/

#areatext{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 1*/
.input_text{
 margin-top: 30px;
 
}

.button{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 155px;
 padding-bottom: 158px;
 padding-left: 105px;
 padding-right: 105px;
 background-color: #ffd694;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:#ff4d00;
 border: 2px dashed orange;
 
}/* Настройка Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/
/*.button:hover{
 transition: all .5s;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}/* Анимация Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/
.add{
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#radio{
 
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 
}/* Настройка радио кнопок*/
.button_radio
{
 margin-top: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}


#check{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
}/* Настройка чек боксов*/
.button_checkbox{
 margin-top: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;

}

#inp{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 3*/
#inp input{
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 240px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 3*/





.add_button_answer{

 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 109px;
 padding-right: 109px;
 background-color: #ffd694;
 font-size: 30px;
 color:#ff4d00;
 border: 2px dashed orange;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*.add_button_answer:hover{
 transition: all .5s;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}/* Анимация Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/


#footer{display: none;

 margin-top: 10000px;
}/* футер*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/cssfortest.css?323" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   let tasks=0;//количество заданий
   let lenghts={};//массив, фиксирующий количество элементов в заданиях, которые можно добавлять
   //форма с textarea
   $('#form_2').click(function(){
    tasks++;
    $('.radiobutton_template:hidden').clone('deepWithDataAndEvents').insertBefore('#form_handler').attr('id','task'+tasks).slideDown(1000,function(){
     $('.radiobutton_template:last .main_text').attr('name','task'+tasks+'[total_task]');
     $('.radiobutton_template:last .icontest #inputfile').attr('name','task'+tasks+'[icontest1][myPhoto]');
     $('.radiobutton_template:last .icontest #text').attr('name','task'+tasks+'[icontest1][task2photo]');
     lenghts['task'+tasks]={'icontest':1};
     $('.radiobutton_template:last #radio .button_radio').attr('name','task'+tasks+'[radio_answer1][radio]');
     $('.radiobutton_template:last #radio .input_text').attr('name','task'+tasks+'[radio_answer1][text_answer]');
     lenghts['task'+tasks]={'radio_answer':1};
    });
   });
   $('.button').click(function(){
    let className=$(this).closest('div').attr('class');//получаем значение класса родительского diva для данной кнопки
    let idName=$(this).closest('div').attr('id');//извлекаем все классы
    className=className.split(' ');//получаем также id, генерируемое при создании diva
    //добавляем div icontest
    $('.'+className[1]+' .icontest:hidden').clone('deepWithDataAndEvents').css('display','none').insertBefore(
    this).slideDown(1000).children().not('#uploadPreview').each(function(index, el){
     //подготавливаем для элементов diva аттрибут name
     if($(this).attr('id')=='inputfile'){
      len=++lenghts[idName]['icontest'];
      $(this).attr('name','task'+tasks+'[icontest'+len+'][myPhoto]');
     }
     else{
      len=lenghts[idName]['icontest'];
      $(this).attr('name','task'+tasks+'[icontest'+len+'][task2photo]');
     }
    });
    
   });
  })
  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="page">
  
  <div id="main_content"><!--  Основной див  сайта -->
  
   <div class="task radiobutton_template">
    <textarea name="task[total_task]"class="main_text" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="Вы лох"> 
    </textarea><!-- Общее задание -->
    <div class="icontest ">
     <img id="uploadPreview" style="width:240px; height: 240px;" />
     <input id="inputfile" type="file" name="task[icontest][myPhoto]" onchange="PreviewImage(this);" accept="image/*" /><!-- Вставить изображение -->
     <textarea class="testtext1" id="text" name="task[icontest][task2photo]" id="" cols="32" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="поздровляю">
     </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
    </div>
       
    <input type="button" class="button add" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
       
    <div id="radio">
     <input id="radiobutton" name="task[radio_answer][radio]" type="radio" value="" class="button_radio">  <!--  радио кнопка -->
     <textarea class="input_text" id="text" name="task[radio_answer][text_answer]" id="" cols="28" rows="1" style="resize:none" placeholder="поздрляю">
     </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="add_button_answer" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
       
   </div>
   <form action="createtest_handler.php" method="post">
   <div id="form_handler">
   <input type="button" value="2 форма" id="form_2">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function PreviewImage(elem) {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(elem.files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                elem.previousElementSibling.src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        };

    </script><!--  Превью Изображения на сайте -->
   
 </div>


 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
lenghts['task'+tasks]={'icontest':1};
...
lenghts['task'+tasks]={'radio_answer':1};
```

Чему, в конце концов, будет равно `lenghts['task'+tasks]`?

Comment: lenghts[task1][icontest]=1,2,3 и т.д.

Comment: @МаксимЛарченко - нет

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка

Comment: спасибо что указали, что я перетираю значение task[task1]

Comment: @МаксимЛарченко Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.